# Heroku/Bootstrap/Rails dropdown menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an issue in a rails app where a boostrap dropdown navigation is not working on the pages served from Heroku - though works fine on local and the page source itself matches on both local and heroku.

The html source from Heroku shows that that bootstrap scripts are not being included in the html file header (but they DO show on local).  No errors are being created

How to I get Heroku to include them?  I have tried

1. editing config/product.rb to inlcude config.serve_static_assets = true​
2. rake asset:precompile.

application.css is empty

application.js:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

_navigation.html.erb (as per bootstrap code sample):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to "@lpha-blog", root_path, class: "navbar-brand", id: "logo" %>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li><%= link_to "Articles", articles_path %></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Actions <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "New Article", new_article_path %></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "log out", logout_path, method: :delete %></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

These are the inclusions when served locally (when view source in my browser):

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/custom.self-59ff28861b851de8260852e29f100100e4e03106990fffe133d6662598008f83.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-f0d704deea029cf000697e2c0181ec173a1b474645466ed843eb5ee7bb215794.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
    <script src="/assets/rails-ujs.self-551fbd47b981dacbb84a270f9123074caf39eb72aaf6f478ab597c6f81435e4b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.self-6ad2488465135ab731a045a8ebbe3ea2fc501aed286042496eda1664fdd07ba9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.self-742145c5bb847aafdadc6e339be795628f8bc25f177e851f03a8c42278eb0312.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/button.self-126ac9bf0e7f2d8568f8da3a00fd5f0fac6eae0946331003370161fbf8d7975e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.self-e47323f363ceb3dc0bdbce05e36e709ed428e339833a41140a85cb0af24b8127.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.self-2eb697f62b587bb786ff940d82dd4be88cdeeaf13ca128e3da3850c5fcaec301.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.self-561cca1cbaf67474e01e9536f106bad541594860a6df997004591c1c1957a147.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.self-3e78617ade5663314b7ee0ea10375a5b34d59ffbade44939e3f2a4e4ef2019b3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.self-5bf7078b682f8b131332eefa46b45fa5eff2eca745fc0d03e2991450888f7c28.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/affix.self-6d6f1a7fc5c8aabf3547fa1b794fab6268f54bc55ad815e55873c71f52513517.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.self-969f3c5f48cdf1e439c7fa1154c13b948715f5c689f87837c0b64521d3b46ef6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.self-05afb177e08f98997ccfc84fa08a215e4b27d48d5fe4d049080675e9dffd8199.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.self-0aa93860b59fe7393f1dd490f54b3cb994f9d6155adffce034d4e14ae361b041.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets.self-fbfa5ad7d9aa0afe439ec4ff3883acc4cb92b62cb67c40d674320c9aa1d4642d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/activestorage.self-6e8d967adecc8b2a7259df0f51ef5b6f171c33267c7d149a474beccd90c68697.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-2db6ec539b9190f75e1d477b305df53d12904d5cafdd47c7ffd91ba25cbec128.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/action_cable.self-69fddfcddf4fdef9828648f9330d6ce108b93b82b0b8d3affffc59a114853451.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/cable.self-8484513823f404ed0c0f039f75243bfdede7af7919dda65f2e66391252443ce9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-5e866087125b4eb5e02a8365d73cdaeb7f2127bbb3f479fb54ab3ddb0d5c66af.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

This is what i get from heroku:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-40046fb6642443a8a7c1e1a06679d80e1cf2418e0a556bc8bef86fc8ef5034b6.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<script src="/assets/application-e7dcf169b5330c2d67149180eb56f8d15f202011f690b430b4b888baadd1a701.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

https://github.com/drewjohnston/alpha-blog

Comment: have you commited your public folder and pushed it to heroku?

Comment: Hi Alvaro, yes committed.  Everything is there, the Heroku headers are just not including the various bootstrap js files.

Comment: Could you update your question with these files? application.js, application.css, and the _layout.html.erb ? It will help to find the bug

Comment: Ahh.. so it is included in the /assets/application-xx.js .. which means it is a more likely a js problem.

Comment: Rails minify your js files into one in production, to do it you should run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`, commit generated files and push to heroku

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, was already ahead of you on that - even went down the webpacker route...  The files all seem to be there now.. but the dropdown UI is still not functioning.  I am giving up on Heroku and have set up an EC2 instance instead.. (which is working fine)

Comment: It is very strange.. same code base - when deployed to Heroku everything seems to be there, but the javascript for the Bootstrap dropdowns just doesn't work.  When deployed to AWS the bootstrap downloads do work.. when deployed to gcloud it doesn't work.  I made a guess it could be a windows related 'bug' but I also tried deploying the same code base to a fresh Heroku instance from a Linux box.. still no dropdown's.

Comment: GCloud app deploys your rails app as a Docker application under the hodd, so you have to do some different configs, btw, Have you tried to use some bootstrap gem? Maybe it could fix your asset pipeline.